# Angular 9 Type any[] | ReceiptResponse is not assignable to type

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using HttpClient to retrieve records from a JSON api through a service, .  I created a class that represents the object returned from the api identically, however, I'm getting the following error.

`Type 'any[] | ReceiptResponse' is not assignable to type 'ReceiptResponse'`

my service has the following function:

```
getPagedReceipts(
  filter = '',
  sortOrder = 'ASC',
  sortColumn = 'receipt.id',
  pageNumber = 0,
  pageSize = 5,
): Observable<ReceiptResponse> {
     return this.http.get<ReceiptResponse>(this.baseUrl, {
       params: new HttpParams()
         .set('filter', filter)
         .set('sortOrder', sortOrder)
         .set('sortColumn', sortColumn)
         .set('pageNumber', pageNumber.toString())
         .set('pageSize', pageSize.toString())
     }).pipe(
       catchError(this.handleError)
     );
}
```

I'm calling this in the following function.

```
public receiptsResponse: ReceiptResponse;

this.receiptService.getPagedReceipts(filter, sortOrder, sortColumn,
  pageIndex, pageSize).pipe(
  catchError(() => of([])),
  finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
).subscribe(receiptsResponse => {
  this.receiptsResponse = receiptsResponse; <-- this is location of the error.
  this.receipts = this.receiptsResponse.items; 
  console.log(this.receiptsResponse);
  this.receiptsSubject.next(this.receipts);
});
```

This is ReceiptResponse:

```
import {Receipt} from './receipt';

export class ReceiptResponse {
  public itemCount: number;
  public items: Receipt[];
  public next: string;
  public pageCount: number;
  public previous: string;
  public totalItems: number;


  constructor(
    itemCount?: number,
    items?: Receipt[],
    next?: string,
    pageCount?: number,
    previous?: string,
    totalItems?: number

  ) {
    this.itemCount = itemCount;
    this.items = items;
    this.pageCount = pageCount;
    this.next = next;
    this.previous = previous;
    this.totalItems = totalItems;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of your `catch` block which returns an observable of an empty array

```
catchError(() => of([])),
```

Try returning null instead

```
catchError(() => of(null)),
```